# MvvmCross: Error with JSON in SimpleRestService.cs

Tags: json, mvvm, xamarin, mvvmcross

I'm trying to run through Lesson 6 in N+1 Days of MvvmCross but cannot get the SimpleRestService to work.

> 05-22 16:14:38.156 I/mvx     ( 2849):  40.20 Problem creating viewModel of type MapViewModel - problem MvxException: Failed to resolve parameter for parameter jsonConverter of type IMvxJsonConverter when creating MyApp.Core.Services.SimpleRestService
>
> Cirrious.CrossCore.Exceptions.MvxException: Failed to load ViewModel for type MyApp.Core.ViewModels.MyViewModel from locator MvxDefaultViewModelLocator

The SimpleRestService.cs is identical to that of the tutorial, except for namespace, as is the interface.

```
namespace MyApp.Core.Services
{
public class SimpleRestService
    : ISimpleRestService
{
    private readonly IMvxJsonConverter _jsonConverter;

    public SimpleRestService(IMvxJsonConverter jsonConverter)
    {
        _jsonConverter = jsonConverter;
    }

    public void MakeRequest...
    private void MakeRequest...
    private T Deserialize<T>(string responseBody)
    {
        var toReturn = _jsonConverter.DeserializeObject<T>(responseBody);
        return toReturn;
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error message says:

> MvxException: Failed to resolve parameter for parameter jsonConverter of type IMvxJsonConverter when creating MyApp.Core.Services.SimpleRestService

This suggests you don't have an `IMvxJsonConverter` registered with IoC

Have you got one? e.g.:

- have you referenced and initialised the Json plugin in the UI project? (Nuget does this for you if you add the plugin)
- or (advanced option) have you created and registered your own IMvxJsonConverter?

In the N+1 N=6 video, the Json plugin is added at approx 13:13 - see http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=He6QvnLsPUA&feature=youtu.be&t=13m13s

Comment: Spot on. I'd installed the NuGet package to Core but not to the Droid project. Thank you!